# Mobx Generic Observer using Typescript typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, mobx, mobx-react-lite

I would like to wrap the following function in mobx's `observer()`, but can't seem to figure out how to do that (or if it's possible) while maintaining the generic typing:

```
interface GenericProps<T> {
  arg: T;
}
const foo: <T>(props: GenericProps<T>) => T = (props) => props.arg;
```

This is a global exported function, so using the `@observer` decorator is not an option (I think), I need to use the `observer()` function from mobx-lite-react.

What I want is something like

```
interface GenericProps<T> {
  arg: T;
}
const foo = observer<T>((props: GenericProps<T>) => props.arg);
```

Probably related to https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite/issues/243, but from the conversation it is not clear to me how I would go about implementing the generic observer in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your sample is not react component, you need to match `React.FunctionComponent` interface

```
const foo_1: <T>(props: GenericProps<T>) => React.ReactElement | null = (props) => <>{JSON.stringify(props.arg)}</>;
```

2. add observer (this should work already thanks improvements in TS 3.4 or 3.5)

```
const foo_2: <T>(props: GenericProps<T>) => React.ReactElement | null = observer((props) => <>{JSON.stringify(props.arg)}</>);
```

3. if on older TS you need to move type declaration to the function itself (note the `extends unknown` which tells compiler this is generic definition and not JSX tag, return type doesn't need to be specified since it will be inferred)

```
const foo_3 = observer(<T extends unknown>(props: GenericProps<T>) => <>{JSON.stringify(props.arg)}</>);
```

Comment: Yup, 2. works for me - thank you! The key was that I wasn't typing the function properly; then observer itself doesn't have a direct reference to the type but that's ok for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
interface GenericProps<T> {
  arg: T
}

const foo = <T extends IReactComponent>(props: GenericProps<T>) => observer(props.arg)
```

I am not quite understand because in the first example you have function which returns another function, but in the second example you just pass function to `observer` but it is not possible since observer only accepts something that extends `IReactComponent`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! First question, what is `IReactComponent`? re: your question, the function being passed to observer just updates some store based on values stored in mobx (it returns nothing/void), hence wanting to wrap it in observer to that the logic is rerun when necessary.

Comment: IReactComponent  is MobX helper type, basically `type IReactComponent<P = any> = React.ClassicComponentClass<P> | React.ComponentClass<P> | React.FunctionComponent<P> | React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<P>`. If you just want to update store, without rendering something, why would you even use `observer`? Isn't `reaction` or `autorun` would serve better?